# Nginx+Tornado static files aren't being handled by nginx, why?

Tags: python, nginx, config, tornado

I'm trying to set up Tornado server behind nginx proxy, here're the relevant bits of the configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location html/ {
        root /srv/www/intj.com/html;
        index login.html;
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        rewrite (.*) /html/favicon.ico;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        rewrite (.*) /html/robots.txt;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
    }
}
```

I can get to my Python server through nginx, but when I request a static pages, such as, say `login.html`, which is located in `/srv/www/intj.com/html/login.html`, instead of loading the static file, the request is forwarded to Tornado, which doesn't know what to make of it.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `login.html` is like `http://example.com/login.html`? or `http://example.com/html/login.html`?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady It's the second. Sorry, forgot to mention it.

Comment: And the `if` is supposed  to make sure there's no query sting?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady ummm... no, my understanding was that this is only relevant to caching. I.e. if someone requested a resource (it could be an HTML page) providing some query string, that page should not be cached. For example, if you did not log in successfully, the response login page must expire (and not be served again by mistake). It would be really odd if that's not what it does...

Comment: according to http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#if, I think you're doing the opposite, i think it should be something like `if(!$query_string)` or something like that

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady thanks for your help. I'll probably just drop it altogether. After some thought, it doesn't look like this rule will be serving anything dangerous, so I'll just let it be. Until some day when I know better what to do with it :)

Comment: ill post an answer with what i think might work

Answer (score 0):

Well, it actually had to be `^~ /html/`, but I don't really know what it means / what is the difference, so it would be cool if someone could enlighten me.

Comment: I think `/html/` instead of `html/` should work but i did not try this. Every normal path requested via http should start with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me how it goes.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        if($query_string) {
            root /srv/www/intj.com/html;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/;
        }
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
    }
}
```